# converting blob to data url

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I've been trying to create dataurl from an image blob in vuejs but I keep getting the error

`'Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: Failed to execute 'drawImage' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The provided value is not of type '(CSSImageValue or HTMLCanvasElement or HTMLImageElement or HTMLVideoElement or ImageBitmap or OffscreenCanvas or SVGImageElement or VideoFrame)'."`

my blob url is looks like - `blob:http://localhost:8080/ca6d6419-f933-439b-8a16-62a80c81ab1a`

I've tried doing this so far

```
   upload() {
      this.value = blob:http://localhost:8080/ca6d6419-f933-439b-8a16-62a80c81ab1a;
      var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
      canvas.width = this.value.width;
      canvas.height = this.value.height;
      canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(this.value[0], 0, 0);
      dataURI = canvas.toDataURL();
      console.log(dataURI);
    },
```

update:

```
   upload(){
      this.value = blob:http://localhost:8080/ca6d6419-f933-439b-8a16-62a80c81ab1a;
      let img = document.createElement('img');
      img.src = this.value;
      let canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
      canvas.width = img.width;
      canvas.height = img.height;
      canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(img[0], 0, 0);
      dataURI = canvas.toDataURL();
      console.log(dataURI);
}
```

Comment: Just create an `img` element, assign that the blob source, and then use that as first parameter for `drawImage`?

Comment: I created a canvas element. isn't that same? @CBroe

Comment: First of all, no, and second, I did not say replace the canvas with something else.

Comment: I receive the blob url as a prop. How do I use the blob prop on an img element ?

Comment: @CBroe I've updated the question. can you check what I'm doing wrong there

Comment: @helpmepiliizzz have you tried to `drawImage` at `img.onload`?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is on `drawImage` because as first parameters it wants `CSSImageValue or HTMLCanvasElement or HTMLImageElement or HTMLVideoElement or ImageBitmap or OffscreenCanvas or SVGImageElement or VideoFrame`.

Try to create an image from your blob:

```
var img = new Image();
img.src = URL.createObjectURL(yourBlob);
```

And then on image load, call `drawImage` passing `img`:

```
img.onload = function(){
   var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
   canvas.width = this.value.width;
   canvas.height = this.value.height;
   canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(img, 0, 0);
}
```

Comment: I did use onload but now the data url isn't being assigned to a state. like `this.url = canvas.toDataURL()` isn't working

Comment: @helpmepiliizzz could be due to the fact that on `onload` you couldn't access to `this`.

Comment: so how am I suppose to access it then? wouldn't the conversion not work without onload?

Comment: @helpmepiliizzz I think you have to wait onload to drawImage and I have never had necessity to access to this in this way. Let me see if I found something on internet...

Comment: please let me know if you find the solution

Comment: @helpmepiliizzz I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68726911/state-not-assigned-inside-onload-function). happy that you solved =). If you found this answer useful, please don't forget to set it as correct answer. Have a nice coding =)

Answer (score 0):

```
function convertBlobToDataUrl(blob) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
    reader.onloadend = function () {
        console.log(reader.result);
    };
}
```

Comment: I get `Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: Failed to execute 'readAsDataURL' on 'FileReader': parameter 1 is not of type 'Blob'."` error

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL