# state not assigned inside onload function

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, blob, vuejs3

I'm trying to assign the data url of an image to a state but it isn't being assigned to the state. First I convert a blob url to data url and then assign it to a state in vuejs, however, the state doesn't have the data url.

The imgSrc does show the data url for the console log inside the onload function. but if I use the state imgSrc in any other function then it shows the blob url instead of the data url.

```js
//suppose I have a blob url and it's passed as a prop

value = blob:http://localhost:8080/ca6d6419-f933-439b-8a16-62a80c81ab1a

upload() {
      this.imgSrc = this.value;
      let img = new Image();
      img.src = this.value;
      img.onload = function () {
        var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        canvas.width = img.width;
        canvas.height = img.height;
        canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(img, 0, 0);
        const dataURI = canvas.toDataURL();
        this.imgSrc = dataURI;
        console.log('imgSrc inside', this.imgSrc); //shows data url
      };
      console.log('imgSrc outside', this.imgSrc); //shows blob url
    },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this` inside the `onload` callback doesn't refer to the vue instance , to make it refer you should assign `this` to a global variable then use that variable inside the callback :

```
upload() {
      this.imgSrc = this.value;
      let img = new Image();
      img.src = this.value;
     let vm=this;
      img.onload = function () {
        var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        canvas.width = img.width;
        canvas.height = img.height;
        canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(img, 0, 0);
        const dataURI = canvas.toDataURL();
        vm.imgSrc = dataURI;
        console.log('imgSrc inside', vm.imgSrc);
      };
     //any code here will be ran before the callback 
    },
```

Comment: oh wow, I didn't know this. thanks so much

Comment: btw why is `this` not referred to the vue instance?

Comment: you're welcome, because it refers to the context of the onload callback